# How to determine all events in Jenkins that Started by timer?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-scriptler

I inherited a Jenkins server that has a lot of redundant processes and mixture of plugins and scriptlers.  I have one process that runs on a weekly bases, but can't seem to locate the origin of this process.  Is there any way to get a list of everything in Jenkins that is scheduled to be "Started by timer"